# Error when Using BiomartGeneRegionTrack in cummeRbund package

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, biomart

I am trying to plot a gene of interest using cummeRbund package. Using this script:

```
biomTrack<-BiomartGeneRegionTrack(genome=genome, chromosome=as.character(myChr), start=myStart, end=myEnd, name="ENSEMBL", showId=T)
```

I encountered this error:

```
     Error in .getBiomart(genome) : 
         Gviz thinks that the UCSC genome identifier 'hg38' should map to the current Biomart head as 'GRCh38', but its current version is 'GRCh38.p5'.
       Please manually provide biomaRt object.
```

using `useMart("ensembl",dataset="hsapiens_gene_ensembl")` also couldn't help. Would you please tell me how can I fix this?

Here is the `sessionInfo()`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
 [1] grid      stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] biomaRt_2.28.0       cummeRbund_2.14.0    Gviz_1.16.1          rtracklayer_1.32.1   GenomicRanges_1.24.2
 [6] GenomeInfoDb_1.8.1   IRanges_2.6.0        S4Vectors_0.10.1     fastcluster_1.1.20   reshape2_1.4.1      
[11] ggplot2_2.1.0        RSQLite_1.0.0        DBI_0.4-1            BiocGenerics_0.18.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] SummarizedExperiment_1.2.3    VariantAnnotation_1.18.1      splines_3.3.0                
 [4] lattice_0.20-33               colorspace_1.2-6              htmltools_0.3.5              
 [7] GenomicFeatures_1.24.2        chron_2.3-47                  interactiveDisplayBase_1.10.3
[10] XML_3.98-1.4                  survival_2.39-4               foreign_0.8-66               
[13] ensembldb_1.4.2               BiocParallel_1.6.2            RColorBrewer_1.1-2           
[16] matrixStats_0.50.2            plyr_1.8.4                    stringr_1.0.0                
[19] zlibbioc_1.18.0               Biostrings_2.40.2             munsell_0.4.3                
[22] gtable_0.2.0                  latticeExtra_0.6-28           Biobase_2.32.0               
[25] BiocInstaller_1.22.2          httpuv_1.3.3                  AnnotationDbi_1.34.3         
[28] Rcpp_0.12.5                   xtable_1.8-2                  acepack_1.3-3.3              
[31] BSgenome_1.40.1               scales_0.4.0                  Hmisc_3.17-4                 
[34] XVector_0.12.0                mime_0.4                      Rsamtools_1.24.0             
[37] gridExtra_2.2.1               AnnotationHub_2.4.2           digest_0.6.9                 
[40] stringi_1.1.1                 biovizBase_1.20.0             shiny_0.13.2                 
[43] tools_3.3.0                   bitops_1.0-6                  magrittr_1.5                 
[46] RCurl_1.95-4.8                dichromat_2.0-0               Formula_1.2-1                
[49] cluster_2.0.4                 Matrix_1.2-6                  data.table_1.9.6             
[52] httr_1.2.0                    R6_2.1.2                      rpart_4.1-10                 
[55] GenomicAlignments_1.8.3       nnet_7.3-12
```